# How can I solve an error when I migrate my Django models?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I want to migrate my model for create tables on my local PgSQL DB.
It's not the first time that I'm doing that on this configuration but this time, that's fail.

#### My manipulation :

1) I deleted my old database **jlb_inventory**

2) I recreated the database **jlb_inventory** empty

3) I deleted "0001_initial" on application's directory `/migration`

4) I ran command `python manage.py makemigrations` => **Error**

models.py

```py
# Table Etude
class Study(models.Model):
    study_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)



class Inventory(models.Model):
    watercourse = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    town = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    number_resorts = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    inventory_date = models.DateField(null=False)
    fk_study = models.ForeignKey(Study, on_delete=models.CASCADE)



class Resort(models.Model):
    index_resort = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    name_resort = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    fk_inventory = models.ForeignKey(Inventory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Taxon(models.Model):
    name_taxon = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    gi = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class Sample(models.Model):
    MICRO_HABITAT_CHOICES = (
        ('1', 'Habitat1'),
        ('2', 'Habitat2'),
        ('3', 'Habitat3'),
        ('4', 'Habitat4'),
        ('5', 'Habitat5'),
        ('6', 'Habitat6'),
        ('7', 'Habitat7'),
        ('8', 'Habitat8'),
    )

    taxon_quantity = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    fk_taxon = models.ForeignKey(Taxon, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fk_resort = models.ForeignKey(Resort, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And my error

```py
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "business_data_entry_taxon" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ame_taxon", "business_data_entry_taxon"."gi" FROM "business_...
```

Someone knows what is the problem here ?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you run `migrate`?

Comment: Same thing with ```migrate``` command

Comment: Do migrations applied or throw an error when run `migrate`? If so, then you can follow these 1. create a fresh database 2. delete all migrations files 3. run makemigrations and migrate command.

Comment: Did you deleted the whole database or only this tables?

Comment: @shafik, that's the problem. Your description is exactly what I did before my post...

Comment: Haven't delved into how Django deals with migrations but could it be it's like in other systems and you still have a table in your database that is keeping track of already applied migrations?

Comment: @epsilonmajorquezero I deleted all the whole db and i created a new that uses the same name.

Comment: Ok, then it's probably not what I was thinking of.

Comment: Maybe you missing something. Do you update the new database name in settings.py?

Comment: @shafik Yes i did and Django found it

Answer (score 0):

I tested your app and it is working(django 2.2). If you delete db and recreate new db so normally it is working but somehow I think you need first migration for your db.

So, remove app INSTALLED_APPS, and recreate db and remove all migrations. Then run  makemigrations and migrate. Then add your app to INSTALLED_APPS, run again makemigrations and migrate.

Comment: I did it and i've a new error : ```RuntimeError: Model class business_data_entry.models.Study doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.```.. I don't understand how Django knows that i've this app because i "undeclared" with this manip.

Comment: django knows your app name apps.py, so maybe you changed your app name in this file or maybe you changed your app folder name before..

Comment: I did it successfully. I ran ```makemigrations``` and Django return ```No changes detected```. I ran ```migrate``` and Django did migrations well. I re-added all my changes and ```makemigration/migrate```... same error.

Comment: which error ? normally you say db migration error and then app error..
what is your app folder name and what is your AppConfig class name and name info into app.py

Comment: by the way, I think your steps dosnt right. 
1- remove app for INSTALLED_APPS
2- remove migration files
3 - recreate your db
4 - makemigrations
5 - migrate
6 - Add your app to INSTALLED_APPS
7 - makemigrations
8 - migrate

Comment: Sorry, same error = initial error : ```django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "business_data_entry_taxon" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ame_taxon", "business_data_entry_taxon"."gi" FROM "business_...```

Comment: I did exactly what you proposed in your step by step. (thanks you so much for your time)

Answer (score 0):

I post an aswer but I don't have a structuration explication about the solution.

In my app, I've 4 forms and 2 call the DB for `ChoiceField`.
I tried to comment all my `path` in `urls.py` and ran command `makemigrations` and `migrate`. **That's work**...

I think, before execute the command, Django "compile" (or something like that) my code and try to set ChoiceField but he can't find something because I deleted the DB before.

I encourage someone to comment this post for more explications then, i'll edit this aswer.